# Why I use if-else with equals not working?

Tags: java, android, if-statement

Why does setText() show "N/A" when `Info2` = ""? Why does data appear when `Info2` has data but when `Info2` does not have data my setText() call shows blank, not "N/A"?

```
JSON CODE >> {"AirlineInfoResult":{"name":"Malaysian Airlines System","shortname":""}}

String Info2 = ... do something util receive result from shortname

if(Info2.equals("")) {
    shortname.setText("N/A");
}
else if(!Info2.equals("")) {
    shortname.setText(Info2);
}
```

Comment: `if(Info2.equals("") || Info2 == null)`

Comment: Try `Info2.isEmpty()`. And please name it `info2` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Actually it's not duplicate of that question, read it again.

Comment: Improvement: let variable names start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Close vote retracted.

Comment: @A.S. - Might need to switch those conditions (I believe if `Info2 == null` that will result in an NPE)

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan How did you retract it? :/ I never saw that option.

Comment: @A.S. the second part of your statement will never be true, as if it was, you will be getting a nullpointerException on the first part.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Clicked close again. That offered a "retract close vote" option.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Must be a new feature.. Or I was high from the first day on SO.

Comment: `TextUtils.isEmpty(Info2)`, it checks also for null values

Comment: By the way, you have a [`TextUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html) class which has this `isEmpty` method that receives a `CharSequence` e.g. a `String`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shortname.setText((Info2 == null) || Info2.isEmpty()) ? "N/A" : Info2);
```

or,

```
shortname.setText("".equals(Info2) ? "N/A" : Info2);
```

Comment: You should do null check first...

Comment: `(Info2 == null)` is unreachable since an exception will be thrown before you reach it if `Info2` is `null`.

Comment: thanks for the quick response.. wasn't thinking. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
if(Info2.equals(""))
{
    shortname.setText("N/A");
}
else
{
    shortname.setText(Info2);
}
```

By default else is ran if your condition is false. Also keep in mind if Info2 can be null then you should add:

```
if("".equals(Info2))
{
    shortname.setText("N/A");
}
else
{
    shortname.setText(Info2);
}
```

The phrase "".equals(Info2) is called a yoda expression and returns false if Info2 is null.

Comment: Or easier: `"".equals(Info2)`...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That seems harder to read (but I'm in awe I've actually never thought of it that way...)

Comment: That's called a yoda expression, it helps prevents NPEs.

Comment: Hmm I wish I knew that earlier...